# How to get the row value from Qtable widget

Tags: qt

Actually i am inserting combo box in one column on my table and when one of the combo box from the table is selected i want to get the row value . How this can be done ?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include"QComboBox"
#include "QDebug"
#include "QModelIndexList"
#include "QTableWidgetItem"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

QComboBox *s = new QComboBox;
s->insertItem(1,"INt");
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(1,1,s);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
 qDebug("ROW %d",index.row());
}
```

I tried something like this but it didnt give the row value where i have inserted the combo box and from other places it was returning the row value

Comment: Can you please give a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You can edit your question and put your MRE above. Would enhance the readability. :-)

Comment: I have added my full code

Comment: *one of the combo box from the table is selected*. what you mean by this? when the user selects a value from the combobox? your code suggests you want to do something with the value, when the user *clicks* on the *table*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what you are trying to achieve, but maybe you are looking for a `ItemDelegate` that can be set for specific rows or columns, but not for a specific element inside the table. Maybe the posted solution would help you to create minimal reproducible examples.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class ComboBoxDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate{

public:

    virtual QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const override
    {
        auto s = new QComboBox(parent);
        s->insertItem(1, "First");
        s->insertItem(2, "Second");
        return s;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);
    auto table = new QTableWidget;
    table->setRowCount(2);
    table->setColumnCount(2);
    table->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, new ComboBoxDelegate);

    auto s = new QComboBox;
    s->insertItem(1, "First");
    s->insertItem(2, "Second");
    table->setCellWidget(1, 1, s);
    QObject::connect(table, &QTableWidget::itemChanged, [&](QTableWidgetItem* item) {
        qDebug() << item->row();
    });
    table->show();
    app.exec();
}
```